# How to read properties file from Jenkins 2.0 pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, jenkins-pipeline, environment

I am attempting to write a pipeline script to use with Jenkins 2.0 to replicate our existing build.  This original build used the envInject plugin to read a Java properties file, but I can't see how to do this from the pipeline Groovy script.  I have Googled and found the following, but it doesn't work (FileNotFoundException):

```
Properties props = new Properties()
File propsFile = new File('./Builder/project.properties')
props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
```

Thanks!

Comment: with the code shown, if the properties file is on the **classpath** then just use `new File('project.properties')`. if not on the classpath then change to an **absolute** path e.g. `new File('C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\project.properties')`

Comment: Thanks, the absolute path is part of the Jenkins workspace checkout, so would be reluctant to hard-code it.  Not sure how the classpath is set in Jenkins build?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just fought with this yesterday and today.  I wish the availability of this was easier to find.

Grab the '[Pipeline Utility Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text)' plugin.

Use the readProperties step.

```
 def props = readProperties  file: 'dir/my.properties'
```

One word of warning - what I expected to be booleans in the properties files were treated as strings.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that, however it doesn't work nearly as well as the old Env plugins.  I have two properties:

SOFTWARE.VERSION=3.6
RELEASE=${SOFTWARE.VERSION}

This worked fine in the old Jenkins version, but Jenkins 2.0 fails to recognise the RELEASE parameter as 3.6

Comment: @PeteSingleton those properties should be on separate lines.

Comment: Hi, they are on separate lines (copy/paste issue!):

Comment: There is a interpolate argument to readProperties: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadPropertiesStep/help.html#L69

Comment: To get Library's resource, you must use command> libraryResource 'dir/my.properties'.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619093/how-to-read-properties-file-from-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-script/59305175#59305175

Comment: Couldn't get ANYTHING to work... UNTIL I realized that the enclosing method was  a static method being called within a CONSTRUCTOR.. that won't work. The fix was to call the method AFTER the constructor and remove the @NonCPS.

Answer (score 20):

I tried out and below works perfectly fine:

```
test.properties
Monday=abcdef
Tuesday=kfgh

def props = readProperties  file:'/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/test.properties'
def Var1= props['Monday']
def Var2= props['Tuesday']
echo "Var1=${Var1}"
echo "Var2=${Var2}"
```

Comment: I keep getting file locks using this approach

Comment: Can you tell me how to update the value and write it back.

Comment: It was very useful for use by way of example.

Comment: @Gentle It's not possible to update the properties file with the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin. However, you can just read all properties, then format and write them back, for example using echo.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
def props = readProperties file: 'config/general.properties'
```

In case your properties file located in Groovy Library, and source code located in different place, you should use the Resources folder from the Groovy Library.

Hence add below line:

```
--> def propFileContent = libraryResource 'config/general.properties'
    def props = readProperties text: propFileContent
```

***Notes:***

- *"config" is some folder inside 'resources' folder*
- *pay attention, in first places used word "file:", in second used "text:"*

Answer (score 0):

readProperties fails for me with following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Groovy map constructors may only be invoked using the 'new' keyword in the sandbox (attempted to construct class java.util.Properties via a Groovy cast)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:185)
```

I just put this helper method at the end of the file:

```
private Properties readProperties(String filePath) {
  String content = readFile filePath
  Properties props = new Properties()
  props.load(new StringReader(content))
  return props
}
```

and used it in the pipeline:

```
Properties props = readProperties("configuration.properties")
```

Answer (score -1):

i wasn't able to figure out how to interpolate the plain text from readProperties, so i just made a workaround to expand the variable.

```
def props = readProperties  file: 'dir/my.properties'
def release = expand_property(props['RELEASE'])

def expand_property(property) {
  def info 
  node("anyUnixNode") {
    info = sh(script: "echo $property", returnStdout: true)
  }
  info = info.trim()
  return info   
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadPropertiesStep/help.html#L69