# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy Map being cast to String

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Getting a strange error that I'm not finding a lot in the documentation for what would be causing it.  I'm having a Map returned in a pipeline groovy lib that is being cast to a String.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'VERSION=1.0.2n.6.2.194
RELEASE=1
EPOCH=10
SOURCE_BASE_URL=https://artifactory-instance1
' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'
```

Code causing the issue:

```
def getVersion() {
    def utils = new Utils()
    //Appears error is here, cast exception from trying to store String to Map
    Map propertiesMap = utils.readPropertiesFileToMap('build.properties', pipelineScript)
    propertiesMap['VERSION'] + "-" + propertiesMap['RELEASE']
}
```

In the Utils class:

```
@NonCPS
Map readPropertiesFileToMap(filepath, pipelineScript) {
  Map map = [:]
  def content = pipelineScript.readFile 'build.properties'
  Properties properties = new java.util.Properties()
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes())
  properties.load(is)

  Enumeration propertyNames = properties.propertyNames()
  while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = propertyNames.nextElement()
    String value = properties.getProperty(key)
    map.put(key, value)
  }
  assert map instanceof Map
  return map
}
```

Nothing is jumping out at the moment.  When first trying I used a Properties object and was attempting to return it, hitting same problem so I went to a Map which is heavily supported and still seeing the issue.

Comment: Any possibility of [using the `readProperties`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644024/3434431) from the [Pipeline Utility Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps)?

Comment: readProperties, this was actually option 1 after we hit the error but we found out we have to do some updates; we have an older version of scripts security.  I think this would work as I could move and replace the util with a 1 line call.  However, what troubles me before I get deep into this is why what I'm seeing is occurring as in future development may need proper returns from helper functions.

Comment: readProperties actually worked; strange with the string conversion.