# Groovy code for reading a key:value from a text file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hashmap, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a config file `config.txt` with following key:values

```
a=1,2,3
b=5,6,7
```

I want to read the keys a nd b using groovy script but its giving following error message:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods withInputStream java.io.File groovy.lang.Closure
```

The code is as under:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File('config.txt')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}

def runtimeString = 'a'
assert properties."$runtimeString" == '1'
assert properties.b == '2'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Even if you were correctly reading the properties file, the value of key `a` would be `1,2,3` and the value of key `b` would be `5,6,7`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read properties file from Jenkins 2.0 pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619093/how-to-read-properties-file-from-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipeline DSL context runs on `master` node even that your write `node('someAgentName')` in your pipeline. `new File` will work only on master.

But you can read data from file via [sh()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script). Something like:

```
def a = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat config.txt | grep a | cut -f2 -d'='").trim()
def b = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat config.txt | grep b | cut -f2 -d'='").trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following in the Groovy console and the assertions pass

```
new File('config.txt').withReader {
   def props = new Properties()
   props.load(it)

   assert props.getProperty('a') == '1,2,3'
   assert props.getProperty('b') == '5,6,7'
}
```