# How to read property from config file inside Jenkins pipeline using Config File Provider Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, configuration-files

I want to parametrize my Jenkins pipeline with a simple properties config file

```
skip_tests=true
```

that I've added to Jenkins Config File Managment:

[image: config file management screenshot]

In my pipeline I'm importing this file and try to read from it using the Jenkins Pipeline Config File Plugin.

```
node('my-swarm') {

 MY_CONFIG = '27206b95-d69b-4494-a430-0a23483a6408'

 try {

     stage('prepare') {
         configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "$MY_CONFIG", variable: 'skip_tests')]) {
             echo $skip_tests
             assert $skip_tests == 'true'
         }
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
     print e
 }
}
```

This results in an error:

```
provisioning config files...
copy managed file [my.properties] to file:/home/jenkins/build/workspace/my-workspace@tmp/config7043792000148664559tmp
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
Deleting 1 temporary files
[Pipeline] // configFileProvider
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $skip_tests for 
class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of the other answers and [How to read properties file from Jenkins 2.0 pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619093/how-to-read-properties-file-from-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-script) I found the following code to work:

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "$PBD1_CONFIG", variable: 'configFile')]) {
     def props = readProperties file: "$configFile"
     def skip_tests = props['skip_tests']
     if (skip_tests == 'true') {
        print 'skipping tests'
     } else {
        print 'running tests'
     }
}
```

I had to use readProperties from Jenkins' [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadPropertiesStep/help.html#L69).

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is in property format you can use it in a shell step:

```
sh """
  source ${MY_CONFIG}
  .
  .
  .
"""
```

You would need to export the properties that need to be available on programs that the shell calls (e.g. Maven)

Comment: Thanks Rich! I'll try that if I don't find an easier way to get to the properties via configFileProvider.

Comment: Rich, I didn't manage to export the properties and read them from the pipeline shell. Maybe you could refine your answer in a way that this becomes more clear. Besides that, I meanwhile found a solution using the Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin. I've documented it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You made a wrong usage of Groovy GString, you should wrap `$skip_tests` in `"` or use `skip_tests` directly.

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "$MY_CONFIG", variable: 'skip_tests')]) {
  echo skip_tests
  assert skip_tests == 'true'

  echo "$skip_tests"
  assert "$skip_tests" == 'true'
}
```

**Note**:  the value of `skip_tests` is the file path of the config file which is copied from master to job's workspace. It's not the content of the config file.

Comment: Thanks @yong - this helped me finding the solution.