# Jenkins CI / CD on an Open Source Github project with confidential properties files

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, git-secret

I'm struggling on doing **Jenkins CI/CD pipelines** for an **Open Source project** which has a set of **confidential** .properties files.

The `.properties` files are necessary for maintainability in a Spring boot project, and some of the `.properties` files are confidential, and so must not be disclosed in the open sourced code-base.

> For each confidential .properties we provide an example .properties in the open source.

The question is, how do you smoothly (i.e. automize) incorporate the confidential `.properties` or files in the Jenkins CI/CD pipelines, and have a great version controllability using git over those files? So that those confidential `.properties` can effect durring every CI/CD phase and so in the production.

This seems to be a hard-to-automize challenge, any comments, suggestions or experiences are appreciated!

---

### What I've tried

### [Git secret](https://git-secret.io/)

This is a great solution but it doesn't support Windows, so I can't go with it. (Every alternative to git-secret I've found also doesn't support cross-platform.

Comment: If you are using AWS, maybe you can consider using SSM Parameter Store. It supports history and secured string. You can retrieve secrets from Parameter Store on CI steps.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [Config File Provider Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/config-file-provider-plugin) that was a life saver for me.
It is able to replace entire config files with the ones stored in JK or just tokens in XML , Json etc.

In pipeline, when you want to replace the whole file, it looks something like this:

```
 stage('Add Config files') {
        steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'IDOfTheFileStoredInJenkins', targetLocation: pathToMyFileRelativeToWorkspace/myPropertiesFile')]) {
            // some block, maybe a nice log message
            }
}
}
```

similar  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904636/how-to-read-property-from-config-file-inside-jenkins-pipeline-using-config-file):