# assign jobs inside a folder to specific nodes

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins instance has several job folders that belong to different projects.
Now, for some folders,

- all jobs should run on specific build nodes
- no job from outside of this folder should run on these specific build node

I know this can be done by using labels, but I was wondering if there's a way to configure this on the folder, instead of having to add the label information to all the jobs underneath

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a folder you can set a config file with some environment variables that are later used by the jenkinsfile to "decide" the agent labels. However you will not be able to enforce it and prevent other jobs to reuse those agents.
An example of pipeline woul look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
      AGENT_LABEL = 'nice-label'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            environment {
                AGENT_LABEL = sh(script: 'echo $AGENT_LABEL', returnStdout: true).trim()
            }
            agent {
                label "${AGENT_LABEL}"
            }
            steps {
                // Run build steps here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To see how to read a configfile in jenkins, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904636/how-to-read-property-from-config-file-inside-jenkins-pipeline-using-config-file)

In a more complex but more efficient setup you can dynamically spawn the agents you need for each job before starting to build . For this you need to configure and use the [Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/). This is a [tutorial](https://faun.pub/setup-jenkins-dynamic-build-agents-75652cf36b26)