# How to declare steps jenkinsfile to inject environment variables by reading a properties file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a properties file in my workspace which is not a groovy file , and data is in the format

```
var1=var1
var2=var2
```

How do I define the steps('Declarative') in a stage to inject these values as environment variable for the whole pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the accepted answer to [How to read properties file from Jenkins 2.0 pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619093/how-to-read-properties-file-from-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-script) ? Sounds exactly like your problem.

Comment: I'm reading the file now, but I'm unable to assign the branch revision value(which I'm reading from the file) in the checkout step.

unstash name: 'ci.properties' def props = readProperties  file:'ci.properties'
                            def GIT_APP_REVISION= props['GIT_APP_REVISION'