# Get jenkinsfile environment vars from a file located in a repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to take env vars for different apis from a repo that contains all the .env files(one per api). For example:

Inside /env_file directory:

- foo.env
- bar.env

Is it possible to use a .env file located in a repo to get the env vars instead of having them set manually in environment {}? In case it is, how could be referenced each file in each api stage?
Thanks in advance! Never worked in Jenkinsfile like this before. Sorry if this is a weird question.

Comment: maybe you can adopt this solution that I found for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619093/how-to-read-properties-file-from-jenkins-2-0-pipeline-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject environment into Jenkins pipeline's global variable: `env` which is a Map and the wirepuller of `environment {}`, but it has a limitation:

`Allow insert new environment, NOT allow override existing environment`

If your those .env files has same environment and you need to load them together,  you will run into 'override existing environment' issue.

If you're not in that case,  you can do as following:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Test endpoint A') {
      script {
        def props = readProperties file: 'A.env'
        for (p in props) {
           env[p.key] = p.value
        }
      }
      // other steps
    }
    stage('Test endpoint B') {
      script {
        def props = readProperties file: 'B.env'
        for (p in props) {
           env[p.key] = p.value
        }
      }
      // other steps
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! but how would you read, for example, the file A.env from a repo and access to specific file? I do a checkout from the repo that contains the A.env, but then I can't access to the file, placed inside a folder

Comment: You can use relative path to the repo like `readProperties file: '<folder A>/<folder B>/B.env'`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on this. I realised I am actually reading the file but getting this error: `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods putAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String java.lang.Object. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.`
So I don't know if this is actually because of the for loop (don't think so) or the assignation of values to env array.

Comment: Anyway, I'll mark your answer as correct since it actually let me read different env file for each stage. Thanks!